# How to clear StandardInput of the process?

Tags: c#, process

I have created a process in c# application and can read the outputs and errors of that process. Before executing each command i have cleared the **StandardInput** buffer by using **Flush()**. but it is not working.

How can i clear the StandardInput of the process?

**Note:** The process is still running, i'm just executing the commands only. like executing the commands in cmd.exe.

My code here
**process.StandardInput.Flush(); 
process.StandardInput.Write(command);**

Any help whould be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can. You can read it all, but even then, how do you know where to stop? Are you sure your problem can't be solved by other means?

Comment: I need to clear the input buffer before executing the command once the process is stopped and i know the process ends,

Comment: @spender modified the question

Comment: The standard input buffer of *your* program might have already been sent to the process you're controlling and may be lingering in *its* buffers. There may be no way to clear this buffer.

Comment: Just consider this scenario, in cmd prompt i pressed [tab] key followed by cd command, it display some path, now the input buffer having this commands, now i want to clear it .. Thats it.

Comment: Please paste your code here. So that we can know what you are actually trying and you will get a quick answer.

Comment: That's not in the standard input buffer - that's internal stuff of `cmd.exe`. Maybe you can send something like escape to get rid of it, but I don't think cmd is really designed for this kind of operation - it doesn't make much sense. What are you actually trying to do here?

Answer (score 1):

By the time you've written into Standard Input, it's too late. `Flush` only serves to send the data forth (and I'm not sure if it even does anything in the case of standard I/O - I don't expect it to), it doesn't *clear* anything. If you don't want something on standard input, don't send it in the first place.