# How to know the thread waits for input

Tags: c#, multithreading, process

I am running cmd.exe as a process and enabled its input and output redirects and created threads for **inputreceived** and **outputreceived** events.
how to find **the thread or process waits for input** while executing the process?

Comment: Are you asking if there's a way to detect that a program started through `Process.Start` -> cmd.exe with command line for your program is blocking on the equivalent of `Console.ReadLine`?

Comment: yes @JamesThorpe but during process execution

Answer (score 2):

You don't. You have the input stream, and the output stream - that's it. There's no "waiting for input" flag - that's just there for the user's convenience, not a part of the API.

When you run a process, it is assumed you know how to interact with it - you don't have to *wait* for the process to tell you to provide input. Simply send the data without waiting for "waiting for input".

For example, if you know the process wants to read using three different `ReadLine`s, just send

```
One
Two
Three
```

`ReadLine` isn't really a *request* for data - it simply waits until enough data is present in the input stream. If there already is enough data (that is, the input stream has a `\r\n`), it returns immediately. Now, technically, this does put the thread in a wait state, but that doesn't help you much - you don't know which thread, and you don't know the *reason* for the wait state - it might as well be trying to read a file or something.

Comment: Do you have a answer for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33099594/how-to-clear-standardinput-of-the-process

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this without knowing what the process you are running does.

For example, if you knew that the process executes an action and then prints the result, you could implement sending the action to the process' input stream and waiting for the process to finish (print the message) to the output stream.

You could try using the following to pool the threads of the process:

```
foreach (ProcessThread thread in process.Threads)
    if (thread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Wait
        && thread.WaitReason == ThreadWaitReason.UserRequest)
        ...
```